# Moving files from one dynamic directory to another using batch script

Tags: batch-file, wildcard, windows-7-x64

I need to write a batch script to move files from one sub-directory to another in Windows 7.  These directories have the same structure, and always start with the same characters but end in a random seven digit number.

For example, I need to move all files and folders within `\EMAIL_XXXXXXX\` to `\MAGMA_XXXXXXX\`.  These two sub-directories both exist within the same parent directory `PROJECT_XXXXXXX`. So the MAGMA directory is actually `PROJECT_XXXXXXX\MAGMA_XXXXXXX\`.  Again, the folder numbers will always be random, I just need to run the batch file from within the start of the `PROJECT_XXXXXXX` directory.

I have successfully been able to delete text files from these directories by placing the below batch file within the parent `PROJECT_XXXXXXX` directory:

```
FOR /R %%Y IN (EMAIL*) DO del *.txt /S /Q "%%Y"
```

As you can see above, using wildcards allows me to use batch to find all the directories starting with `EMAIL` and delete all files with the extension .txt.

Now I just need to move the remaining files from the `EMAIL_XXXXXX` sub-directory to the `MAGMA_XXXXXXX` sub-directory.  I understand wildcards can be tricky when manipulating directories.  Is there any way I can move these files in a similar way I was able to delete files, running the batch script within the parent directory?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Will the X be same for one project?

Comment: What have you tried so far, where are you stuck? Please share your efforts!

Comment: Why move files, why not just rename the directory `EMAIL_*` to `MAGMA_*` and vice versa, _(obviously with an intermediate stage name)_. Also the deletion code you are using isn't very good, I'd probably suggest `FOR /D %%A IN (EMAIL_*) DO DEL/Q "%%A\*.txt"`. I've excluded the `/R` and `/S` options as you have made absolutely no mention of sub directories, just `PROJECT_XXXXXXX\EMAIL_XXXXXXX` and `PROJECT_XXXXXXX\MAGMA_XXXXXXX`.